# split into different Strings based on regex in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have requirement to split a string based on Regular expression which will be of the below format.

There are 3 different type of String values -

- ABC_1234_XL.jpg
- XYZ_7890_SM.jpg
- PQ_R_4567_LG.jpg

The regex that I have right now which isn't working is -

```
(^[a-zA-Z])(_\\d+_)([a-zA-Z]$)
```

in the above `ABC`, `XYZ` and `PQ_R` are 3 types of image types which I want to extract separately and compare it with respective list of corresponding Types fetched from DB. 
So in case if I go with normal split by underscore "_", then it flunks the purpose while splitting the 3rd string.

So I need a solution to split these string based on Regular expression, where every time the center element will [0-9] and the left would be Image Type and the right would be Image Size.
Meaning - `ImageType_ImageTypeID_ImageSize`. We need to split this having the center element `(imageTypeID)` as base and get the left & right date by excluding the "_". 
How to achieve this with Split along with Regex?

Help please and let me know in case if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK since no one yet explained your problem then I will try. Your current regex

```
(^[a-zA-Z])(_\\d+_)([a-zA-Z]$)
```

can match only strings with one letter at start, `_`, one or more digits, another `_` and ends with one letter. What you need is regex which accept strings that

- `[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)*` - starts with *one or more* letters and can have optional sequences of `_` and letters (not digits yet)
- `_\\d+_` - have digits surrounded with `_` after it
- `[a-zA-Z]+` have one or more letters after it.
- You probably also want to end your regex with sequence which will match file extension, so you will need something like `[.]jpg`

So try with

```
([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)_(\\d+)_([a-z]+)[.]jpg
```

---

### Demo:

```
String[] data = {
        "ABC_1234_XL.jpg",
        "XYZ_7890_SM.jpg",
        "PQ_R_4567_LG.jpg",
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            "([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)_(\\d+)_([a-z]+)[.]jpg",
   //group 1  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   //group 2                       ^^^^
   //group 3                              ^^^^^^
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for (String s : data) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches())
        System.out.println(m.group(1)+" : "+m.group(2)+" : "+m.group(3));
    else
        System.out.println(s+" doesn't match pattern");
}
```

Output:

```
ABC : 1234 : XL
XYZ : 7890 : SM
PQ_R : 4567 : LG
```

Comment: Let me try this and get back. Thank You Pshemo. :)

Comment: I am glad you like it :)

Comment: Yes. This works and as same as exactly what I wanted. Now I can use these string values for different business logic. Thanks once again mate, :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

([a-zA-Z]*[_]*[a-zA-Z]*)(*\d+*)([\w]+[.][\w]+)

The first group looks for as many characters or _ as it can get
Second group finds the *123123* pattern
And the last one gets you the size and its type.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part is allowed to contain a `_`, I think it is enough to include it in the list of characters of this block :

```
(^[a-zA-Z_]+)(_\\d+_)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

You can even put the delimiters outside of your center block :

```
(^[a-zA-Z_]+)_(\\d+)_([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Comment: thanks. If I put delimiter outside the center block then --> PQ_R_4567_LG.jpg would have problem - when I try to split the string into 3 parts.

Comment: Also, ur first regex works good. But I want to know how to split based on this pattern and assign the 3 parts to 3 different Strings.

Answer (score -1):

`^([A-Za-z_]+)_(\\d+)_([A-Za-z]+)\\.jpg$`

Comment: While it is good to provide solution it is even better to explain how it solves problem.

Comment: thanks. Regex is fine but need a logic to split this into 3 different strings.

Comment: Pshemo - Thanks for the echo